# Property Binding: How to Concatenate String Literals and Binding Value

Tags: sapui5

I have a `StandardItemList` in UI5 like this

```
new sap.m.StandardListItem({
    title: "{BOM/#text}",
    description: "Version: " + "{REVISION/#text}"
})
```

How can I achieve getting the description like "Version: ValueOfTheVersion"?

[image: StandardListItem1]

When I delete the word "Version" in the description it works very well.

[image: StandardListItem2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Rahul!

Adding

```
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
```

to the bootstrap in your index.html will do the trick

### Full Solution

```
<script src="/sapui5/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
        data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.commons,sap.ui.table"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To enable *complex binding syntax*, the recommended way is to add the [bootstrap configuration option](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f2d03b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) `compatVersion` with the value `"edge"`. **E.g.** in index.html:

## `data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"`

This replaces the need for `sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax` since "edge" sets the binding syntax automatically to `"complex"`. Adding `bindingSyntax` makes only sense if the `compatVersion` is lower than `"1.28"`. Options with `xx` should be avoided anyway because they're experimental.

With the *complex binding syntax* enabled, we can make use of

- [`sap.ui.model.CompositeBinding`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0) which includes [Expression Binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0)
- as well as plain `"{path: '...'}"` syntax in XML UI definitions (views or fragments).

Comment: Hi, how to add compatVersion in fiori app, since fiori app did not have index.html, should I put this in component.js?

Comment: @Tina The `compatVersion` as well as `(xx-)bindingSyntax` are already supplied by FLP. You can see how FLP configured the bootstrap in *Technical Information* from [Diagnostics](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6ec18e80b0ce47f290bc2645b0cc86e6). Unfortunately, I'm not aware of how to change those config values for FLP and neither component nor its descriptor supports these kind of attributes. Nevertheless, the binding syntax should be already set to `"complex"` in FLP by default.