# Difference between one-way and one-time binding in UI5

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

What is the difference between one-time and one-way binding in UI5?

Are there any user specific use-cases where I would use each of them?
I could not get much info from the documentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image: Data binding modes in UI5]

## One-way

- **What it does:** unidirectional data flow. Changes in the model data (e.g. via `setProperty`) are steadily propagated to the interested elements in the UI.
- **Use-case:** one prominent example is the [device model](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2) (a one-way JSONModel). It shouldn't accept any user inputs that might update the device information accidentally.

  > We have to set the binding mode to `OneWay` as the device model is read-only and we want to avoid changing the model accidentally when we bind properties of a control to it. By default, models in OpenUI5 are bidirectional (`TwoWay`). When the property changes, the bound model value is updated as well.

## One-time

- **What it does:** one-time data flow. When the binding object is evaluated, its corresponding model data are read and written to the element properties once, and never again.
- **Why it exists:** it all comes down to the number of change listeners. Fewer listeners means less memory allocation and less stuff to maintain during the runtime. The binding mode `OneTime` has thus the potential, compared to other binding modes, to optimize performance and memory consumption.
- **When to use:** for static, non-mutating data.
  *Note:* for property bindings, [`oBindingInfo.value` (since 1.61)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53609552/5846045) can be also defined for static values instead of relying on a model in property binding.
- **Use-case:** the prominent example here is the [`ODataMetaModel`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataMetaModel). From its API reference:

  > This model is **read-only** and thus only supports `OneTime` binding mode. No events are fired!

For more information, see the [documentation topic "Data Binding"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247).

---

### Assigning binding modes in UI5

You can assign one of the [binding mode enum values](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.BindingMode) `'Default'`, `'OneTime'`, `'OneWay'`, or `'TwoWay'` in the following way:

- To a specific binding only:

  ```xml
  <Text text="{ path: '...', mode: 'OneTime' }"/>
  ```
- To all bindings managed by the model:

  ```js
  myModel.setDefaultBindingMode("OneWay");
  ```

  Or in the [app descriptor](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da) in case of a `v2.ODataModel`:

  ```json
  {
    "sap.ui5": {
      "models": {
        "myODataV2Model": {
          "dataSource": "...",
          "settings": {
            "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"
          },
          "preload": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- In [Expression Binding](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) with the following syntax:

  - `myProperty="{:= ...}"` ⇒ `OneTime`
  - `myProperty="{= ...}"` ⇒ `OneWay`
- Custom `formatter` in property bindings (e.g. `value="{..., formatter: '.createText' }"`) as well as composition with string-literals (e.g. `value="My Name is {/name}"`) forces the binding mode to become **`OneWay`**. Use [`type` in order to keep the property binding `TwoWay`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49711462/5846045).