# How to get array length with Expression Binding?

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

As the title implies, I do have the following data:

```
{
  "modelExample": [
    { "id": 0 },
    { "id": 1 },
    { "id": 2 }
  ]
}
```

The JSONModel has three entries, which essentially equates to `3` in `length`.

How do I get the length through an **Expression Binding** statement?

**My Attempt:**

```xml
<Text text="{ ${modelExample>/}.length}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live Update the Number of Items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308896/live-update-the-number-of-items)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here is a sample. Click on <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see it in action:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
], async (Fragment, JSONModel) => {
  "use strict";
  
  // Sample XML definition:
  const definition = '<ObjectStatus title="Length" text="{= ${/modelExample}.length}" class="sapMObjectStatusLarge sapUiTinyMargin" inverted="true" state="Information" xmlns="sap.m" />';
  const control = await Fragment.load({ definition });
  const model = new JSONModel({
    modelExample: [
      { id: 0, /*...*/},
      { id: 1, /*...*/},
      { id: 2, /*...*/},
    ],
  });

  control.setModel(model).placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-on-init="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compat-version="edge"
  data-sap-ui-exclude-jquery-compat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-wait-for-theme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody"></body>
```

As you can see, I'm using `text="{= ${/modelExample}.length}"` which displays the correct length of the array:

[image]

- If the model is named (`"myModel"`), it should be `{= ${myModel>/modelExample}.length}`.
- [Expression binding syntax](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0) requires `{=`  (OneWay) or `{:=`  (OneTime) at the beginning.
- To actually make use of the expression binding in UI5 1.x, either the `bindingSyntax` `"complex"` or the `compatVersion` `"edge"` needs to be set in the bootstrap config as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41554735/5846045). E.g. in `index.html`:

  ```html
  <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="..." data-sap-ui-compat-version="edge" ...>
  ```